# How to trigger onShow callback for Keith Wood jQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Using Keith Wood's datepicker how can I trigger a callback before the datepicker is shown so I can set the picker's parameters?  Using the code below the callback (alert) is shown on page ready and not before the datepicker is shown.

```
$(function(){
   $( ".inputDatePick").datepick({ onShow: alert('on show callback') });
});

....

<input type="text" class="inputDatePick" />
```

Answer (score 3):

doh!  the correct syntax for a callback is a function :

```
$(function(){
   $( ".inputDatePick").datepick({ onShow: function () { alert('on show callback') } });
});
```